# Is Virtualbox 5.2 still maintained and safe?

Tags: debian, virtualbox

Virtualbox really wants to inform me every time I start it that there is a version 6 available.

I'm on 5.2, and I'm on Debian 9.11, if it matters.

Is Virtualbox 5.2 still supported and maintained? Are there security vulnerabilities in the latest 5.2 version?

Why doesn't Debian support Virtualbox 6, when it is pushed so hard from the developers that they need to tell the users every time it starts that they should switch? It seems like I need to manually add it to get version 6.

Comment: [Debian 9 doesn't supply VirtualBox packages](https://wiki.debian.org/VirtualBox#Debian_9_.22Stretch.22). What repo are you getting it from?

Comment: It's supported (by Oracle) until July 2020.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you need to use Virtualbox rather than `kvm` which is built-in to the Linux kernel?   `apt-get install virt-manager` and you've got a nice, easy GUI interface to creating, starting, stopping, etc virtual machines.

Comment: AFAIK, the only remaining reason to use vbox is that it's easy to configure fast graphics in the VM using the host's GPU (i.e. avoids the hassle of configuring passthrough PCI for a 2nd GPU).  Unless you want to play 3D games in a Windows VM or something like that, it's not needed.  virtio graphics is good enough for most other things.

Answer (score 2):

Debian doesn’t support any version of VirtualBox: its support [was ended in Debian 8](https://lists.debian.org/debian-security-announce/2016/msg00280.html), and it isn’t provided in Debian 9 or 10 from the official repositories. The recommended end-user tool for VMs is [`virt-manager`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/virt-manager).

VirtualBox itself [promises support for 5.2 until July 2020](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads). Presumably if you’re running [the latest 5.2 build](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_5_2) you should be safe.